# Need to ask user if they want to repeat with for loop (Python)

Tags: python

```
myList = []
numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter? "))
for numbers in range(1,numbers + 1):
    x = int(input("Please enter number %i: " %(numbers)))
    myList.append(x)
b = sum(x for x in myList if x < 0)
for x in myList:
     print("Sum of negatives = %r" %(b))
     break
c = sum(x for x in myList if x > 0)
for x in myList:
    print("Sum of positives = %r" %(c))
    break
d = sum(myList)
for x in myList:
    print("Sum of all numbers = %r" %(d))
    break
```

I need to figure out how to ask the user if they'd like to use the program again. I haven't learned functions yet, and every time I try to put the entire program into a "while True:" loop, it will only repeat "How many numbers would you like to enter?" Any help is appreciated, I'm inexperienced with python and this has been frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Keep a variable which asks the users if they want to play the game or not and in the end ask them again.

```
k = input("Do you want to play the game? Press y/n")

while k == 'y':
    myList = []
    numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter? ")) 
    for numbers in range(1,numbers + 1):
      x = int(input("Please enter number %i: " %(numbers)))
      myList.append(x)
    b = sum(x for x in myList if x < 0)
    for x in myList:
      print("Sum of negatives = %r" %(b))
      break
    c = sum(x for x in myList if x > 0)
    for x in myList:
      print("Sum of positives = %r" %(c))
      break
    d = sum(myList)
    for x in myList:
      print("Sum of all numbers = %r" %(d))
      break
    k = input("Do you want to play again? y/n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exiting the loop when you hit break, so that won't work either.

Use a while loop, and think of the problem in another way:  Assume the user will enter more input, and ask if he/she wants to quit.

I think this is what you're looking for (assuming you're using Python 3):

```
myList = []

# This variable will change to False when we need to stop.
flag = True

# Run the loop until the user enters the word 'exit' 
#    (I'm assuming there's no further error checking in this simple example)

while flag:
   user_input = input("Please enter a number.  Type 'q' to quit. ")
   if user_input == 'q':
       flag = False
   elif ( . . .  ):   //do other input validation (optional)
       pass
   else:
       myList.append(int(user_input))
       print "The sum of negatives is %d" % sum([i for i in myList if i<0])
       print "The sum of positives is %d" % sum([i for i in myList if i>0])
       print "The sum of all numbers is %d" % sum([i for i in myList])
```